# Scrollbar to be on top of position absolute

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a simple search box which should be on top of the searchable component while scrolling. The problem is that the search box doesn't fit the outer container and just goes through it (`position: absolute`) and overlaps the `up arrow` of the scrollbar.

How can I make the search box fit within the outer container (whole width) and to not overlap the scrollbar?

```css
.container {
  border-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
  height: 140px;
  text-align: left;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid #a0a7b2;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.outer {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
    float: none;
    width: 120px;
}

input {
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border-radius: 4px;
  height: 18px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
}

.search {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    position: absolute;
    width: 99%;
}

.list {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="outer">
     <div class="container">
       <div class="search">
         <input type="text"/>
       </div>
       <div class="list">
         <ul>
           <li>Hola</li>
           <li>Hola</li>
           <li>Hola</li>
           <li>Hola</li>
           <li>Hola</li>
           <li>Hola</li>
           <li>Hola</li>
           <li>Hola</li>
           <li>Hola</li>
         </ul>
       </div>
   </div.
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Post the code here not in CodePen

Comment: Hello. Do not use external links yo provide code as they may become unavailable in the future thus worthless for future users. Share your code here in a workin stackoverflow snipet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes you need to make:

- Modify `overflow to hidden in container class` as well as make it `position:relative`.
- Set the `position of search and list to absolute`.
- Set the `height of list to 100%` and `overflow-y:scroll`.
- Change the `width of input` to 100%.

These modifications changes the code in the following way:

1. Your child containers are now absolutely positioned with relation to the main container.
2. You're not scrolling the main container but only the list containing the unordered list.

```css
.container {
  border-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
  height: 140px;
  text-align: left;
  border: 1px solid #a0a7b2;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.outer {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: none;
  width: 120px;
}

input {
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border-radius: 4px;
  height: 18px;
  width:100%;
}

.search {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  position: absolute;
  width: 99%;
}

.list {
  position:absolute;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="search">
        <input type="text" />
      </div>
      <div class="list">
        <ul>
          <li>Hola</li>
          <li>Hola</li>
          <li>Hola</li>
          <li>Hola</li>
          <li>Hola</li>
          <li>Hola</li>
          <li>Hola</li>
          <li>Hola</li>
          <li>Hola</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      </div. </div>
</body>

</html>
```